# Can someone explain why this Java program that is supposed to reverse a string is not working?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I wrote a Java program that is supposed to reverse a string that you scan it.

```
  import java.util.*;
   public class ReverseString{
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a string");
       String stringtoreverse = sc.nextLine();
      Reverse(stringtoreverse);
  }

  public static void Reverse(String s){
    char a[] = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    String b = a.toString();
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

I tested it and this is what I get.

```
   Enter a string
   hi
  [C@757ecdf0
```

The answer was supposed to be "ih".
Can someone can explain why it doesn't work how I want it to and why I get that output?

Comment: You're calling `toString()` on an array. I suspect you want `new String(a)` instead...

Comment: ladychemicalengineer please consider accepting my answer if it solved your question

Answer (score 0):

To get a human readable format using [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29) use:

```
Arrays.toString(a)
```

or the more minimal `new String(a)`.

Java's `toString()` for an array prints `[`, followed by a character representing the type of the array's elements, then a `@` and then the identity hash code of the array (something like a memory address).